# rename column in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net

in a datatable you can rename column as follows:

```
   dt.Column[0].ColumnName="name";
```

Is it possible to do something similar with `list<MyType>`? I need to retrun list of objects with modified column names. to bind to a gridview some special way.

Comment: Is this asp.net or windows forms? You just want to have custom column names bound to certain properties on MyType correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can go with anonymous types:

```
var yourList = new List<MyType>{ ... };
var newList  = yourList.Select( i=> new { NewColumn = i.OldName });
```

Answer (score 1):

In the asp.net gridviews you can use Bound Fields to Bind Properties and Set the Column Headers to whatever you want

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >           
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="MyProperty" HeaderText="My Custom Column Heaer" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Just make sure the MyProperty exists on the MyType and you should be good.